# why ties.method of rank for repeated value works unexpectedly?

Tags: r, rank

The example of R rank:

```
x1 <- c(3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5)
rank(x1, ties.method= "first")
# [1]  4  1  6  2  7 11  3 10  8  5  9
rank(x1, ties.method= "last")
# [1]  5  2  6  1  9 11  3 10  8  4  7
```

I don't understand why the rank of the second 5 is (8, 8), then I tried to add another two 5 and run the code again:

```
x2 <- c(3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5)
rank(x2, ties.method= "first")
# [1]  4  1  6  7  2  8 13  3 12  9  5 10 11
rank(x2, ties.method= "last")
# [1]  5  2  6 11  1 10 13  3 12  9  4  8  7
```

Why the rank of the second and third 5 are (8, 10) and (10, 8)? I thought they might be (8, 11) (or (8, 7)) and (10, 11) (or (10, 7)).

Comment: Probably relevant: [How does ties.method argument of R's rank function work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34008/how-does-ties-method-argument-of-rs-rank-function-work)

Comment: I read this article before posting my question, it did not solve my confuse.

Comment: please explain why you think this is unexpected

Comment: From the help of rank: "The "first" method results in a permutation with increasing values at each index set of ties, and analogously "last" with decreasing values." So I thought the rank of the 2nd 5 should be (8, 11).

Comment: Following the above comment: since the indexes of value 5 are (7, 8,  9, 10, 11).

Comment: so then the second 5 using "first" becomes the second from last using "last" and that would be 10 not 11

Comment: I see your point, thank you.